# Ошибка в unity CS1061

Tags: c#, unity3d

Все работало буквально 10 минут назад. Создал новую сцену, все так же работало, но потом что-то пошло не так

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.UI;
 using System.Text;
 using static System.Math;

 public class Score : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public Rigidbody2D rgb2d;
     public float topScore = 0.0f;
     public Text scoreText; 

     void Start()
     {
        rgb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
     }


     void Update()
     {
         if (rgb2d.velocity.y > 0 && transform.position.y > topScore)
         {
            topScore = transform.position.y;
            scoreText.text = "Score: " + Mathf.Round(topScore).ToString();
         }
         if (rgb2d.velocity.y < topScore && transform.position.y < topScore - 15)
         {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("1");
         }
     }
}
```

Unity выдает ошибку:

> error CS1061:"'Text' does not contain a definition for 'text' and no
>   accessible extension method 'text' accepting a first argument of type
>   'Text' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)"

подскажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема ? И если сможете донести информацию в понятной для новичка в программировании форме, то буду премного благодарен.

Comment: Уберите `using System.Text;`.

Comment: `using static System.Math;` тоже лишнее.

Comment: А в каком строке ошибка?